# How to join splitted string from two labels to make full string in objective c

Tags: nsstring, uilabel, nsset

I have a string which is split in two labels as label1.text = Hel and label2.text = lo. i want to make it full string as "Hello" when press on a button. How can i get this, Is i have to compare string parts from two labels using set or other some thing. what i do up till now i store the full string in an array and then split it into two sub array as part1 and part2. Again in button press method i make an array which if two parts of string then it stores as in checkArray, so i make two NSSet for checking `isEqualToSet`

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfFullString];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfCheckString];


if([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]){
NSLog("both labels make Hello");
 else{
NSLog("both labels  not make Hello");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
NSString *strHello = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", label1.text, label2.text];
NSLog(@"%@",strHello);
```

Output is like you want